# Grouping two <TR> together to style as TBODY not styling

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I have tried styling the `<tbody>` but it doesn't matter how much of the existing styles I pull out, it doesn't make any difference.

Theoretically,  the following should work, but doesn't...

```css
tbody {
  border: 1px solid #2696A1;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The ultimate goal (unless a better suggestion presents itself) is to wrap the `<tbody>` with a border around two `<tr>` so they are visually identifiable as together. The top `<tr>` is always visible but the second (or more) are not (due to jQuery toggling of the additional information. Normally I would wrap this in a `<div>` and call it a day but I need the table format from the header of this dynamic table so everything stays in it's appropriate columns and doesn't go drifting off into neverland.

Any ideas or suggestions would be fantastic. :-)

Comment: can you post a fiddle containing this issue?

Comment: Style the TD tags, like always ;)

Comment: @c69 the TD tags are not going to show any kind of relationship between the rows, these need to be borders so they appear when printed with the default settings.

Comment: Yes, border-top on TD of top TR, border-bottom on TD of lower TR - gives you illusion of big cells, which are made from two rows.

Comment: @c69 True... And then I can just use a style switch to remove the bottom boarder of the top TR when I toggle the jQuery expand. Awesome answer, though I can't mark it as an answer, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tbody for define boundary as a virtual manner and increase human readability. However instead of styling tbody you can use td tricky way to achieve the goal. Even tr also not a good place to apply styling. You should target td, th etc. Please try following way to apply border:

```
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-spacing: 0px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tbody > tr:first-child > td {
        border-top: 1px solid #2696A1;
    }
    tbody > tr > td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid #2696A1;
    }
    tbody > tr > td:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #2696A1;
    }
    tbody > tr:last-child > td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2696A1;
    }
```